# Logical Database Design(Basic 1:m rule VS. Optional 1:m rule)

Tags: database, relational-database

I have to transform a er diagram into a relation schema. However, I can't tell the difference between Basic 1:M rule and Optional 1:M (Minimal null) rule.

[image]

Comment: I'm sure we know what you are talking about, but those aren't common/standard names. (Although there is a google hit at http://www.javaguicodexample.com/erdrelationalmodelnotes.html.) Please give a reference to where they are from. Please explain what you understand so far. (You could quote the rules, for one thing. You could give an example where you are stuck.) Also, what is your question?

Comment: Please enter all info you can via text. Eg the assignment question and the description of your tables & "relationships"/FKs. Images cannot be searched or used in composing answers. An image *in addition* is good. Also, you still haven't actually asked a question. Also, address my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're following something like http://www.javaguicodexample.com/erdrelationalmodelnotes.html:

> **1-M Relationship Rule:** Each 1-M relationship becomes a FK in the table corresponding to the child type (the entity type near Crow’s Foot symbol). If the minimum cardinality on the parent side of the relationship is one, the FK cannot accept null values (NOT NULL must be used).

Your style of ER [sic] diagram has a box for every table of a design, where a table represents the instances of an application entity type. (Possibly an associative entity type, whose key is a set of other entity ids.) In original ER modeling a "relationship" is an association among entities; but in your style of pseudo-ER diagram "relationship" is used in a confused way sometimes referring to an association and sometimes to a FK (foreign key).

If a "parent" entity type has a 1-to-many (business/application) association/relationship with a "child" entity type then we can model that per a "Basic 1:M rule". We add a NOT NULL FK column to the child table giving the child's parent id. But if the association/relationship is 0-or-1-to-many, ie is optional 1-to-many (ie an erstwhile child doesn't have to have a parent, ie a parent is optional), then we can model that per an "Optional 1:M rule". We add a NULLable FK column to the child table that either gives the child's parent id or NULL if it has no parent.

Initial design:

```
-- T identifies a thing with property ...
thing(t, ...)
-- W identifies a whatsit with property ...
whatsit(w, ...)
```

Now we want to be able to record participants in 1-to-many relationship/association my_1_to_many(t1, w) and 0-or-1-to-many relationship/association my_0_or_1_to_many(t0, w):

```
-- T identifies a thing with property ...
thing(T, ...)
--     W identifies a whatsit with property ...
-- AND my_1_to_many(T1, W)
-- AND (my_0_or_1_to_many(T0, W) OR T0 IS NULL AND NOT my_0_or_1_to_many(T0, W))
whatsit_plus_associated_things(w, ..., t1, t0)
NOT NULL t1
NULL t0
FK (t1) references thing (t)
FK (t0) references thing (t)
```

(You can see why NULL complicates designs compared to just having NULL-free tables `whatsit(w, ...)`, `my_0_or_1_to_many(t, w)` & `my_0_or_1_to_many(t, w)`.)